# Can you remove a clean_field from a form in a view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a form in which I validate a field (`clean_title`).

What I want to do is, delete the `clean_title` method in a`CreateView` view, is there any way to do it?

The problem as such is that I don't want the `title` field validation in an`UpdateView` view, I just want that validation in a `CreateView` view.
(I don't want to create another form I want to reuse this one.)

In case you can't do what I want to do, is there any other alternative?

---

```
# forms.py

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['title', 'subtitle', 'image', 'description', 'status']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Titulo'}),
            'subtitle': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Subtitulo'}),
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs = {'class': 'custom-file-input'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Descripcion'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs = {'class': 'custom-select'}),
        }

        labels = {'title': '', 'subtitle': '', 'image': '', 'description': ''}

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
        if Course.objects.filter(title = title).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Ya existe un curso registrado con ese titulo, elige otro.')

        return title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to override the `__init__` of your form class though and have it accept `*args, **kwargs`. This will give you the ability to send any extra arguments to your form. For example,

views.py

```
def my_first_view(request):
   ...
   form = CourseForm(request.POST or None, title_valid=True)
   ...

ef my_second_view(request):
   ...
   form = CourseForm(request.POST or None, title_valid=False)
   ...
```

forms.py:

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # class meta with all its stuff just like you already did

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # b4 calling super
        self.title_valid = False
        if 'title_valid' in kwargs:
           self.title_valid = kwargs.pop('title_valid', None)
        # now you have title_valid variable to use in your form condition accordingly
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_title(self):
        if self.title_valid:
           # do something
        else:
           # do another
        return title
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: excellent answer! Thank you!. Of course, does the `Meta` class necessarily have to go above `__init__`?

Comment: Glad I could help. No, it does not.